# Issue using selector after converting to configureStore Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I've just converted my reducer from createStore to configure store and now my selectors that I think should be working, don't.

configureStore below

```
import { Dispatch } from 'react';
import { Action, configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import logger from 'redux-logger';

import {
    testReducer,
} from './reducers';

const rootReducer = () => ({
    testReducer
});

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(logger),
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

export const useAppDispatch = (): Dispatch<Action<any>> => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();

export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

selector

```
export const getTest = (state: RootState) => state.testReducer.test;
```

error

```
Property 'test' does not exist on type 'ReducerWithInitialState<TestState>'.ts(2339)
```

The error seems to go away if I add `getInitialState()` after `testReducer.` in the selector but that seems incorrect.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with this setup. Print out the entire output/ state from selector and debug from there.
Maybe share your output from selector if you need further help debugging.

Comment: This is a Typescript error, does the selector actually not work?

Comment: @sushrut619 Another thing that made me suspect it was that in the redux logger it wouldn't show the values in the reducer, just showing it as a function with a method called "getInitialState"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `rootReducer` you have there is a function that returns an object with reducers - that's wrong. Instead just make it an object.

```js
const rootReducer = {
    testReducer
};
```

Comment: Great spot, I didn't think it would make a difference but it does, thanks